# /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found on a ubtuntu machine

Tags: server, glibc

I have an internet-less ubuntu server (amd64) which is accessed via ssh. To install a package i installed "libc6-udeb_2.13-38+deb7u10_amd64.udeb" which messed up everything. Now i get this error

```
sudo: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

on very command that i give. No new ssh connections can be created, only the one that i am working on is live. There is no way i can "apt-get update" as there is no Internet. I cannot manually install the packages as i wont be able to copy them to the server.

This is a very valuable machine and i cannot tweak the OS. I have looked up this problem but the solutions require internet access. I cannot install using flash drive either. I am stuck bad. It is not running any command either.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: yes this one https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libc6-udeb

Comment: No, it still gives the same error "cat: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by cat)"

Comment: No, it does not run any command. I tried purging.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with `libc.so.6` and `GLIBC_2.27`. I spent hours trying to fix it. In the end I just created a new partition and installed Ubuntu on it. Then I mounted the old partition and manually copied over data directories I needed. I feel your pain...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix this is what i am thinking as well. However, this would not export all the valuable installations and the setup that  was done on this server. Is there any way in the world that i could reverse this mess?

Comment: I could still mount the broken partition and compare installed apps to the good fresh install. Then I reinstalled the good apps I really needed. Then I copied over there configuration files. Of course I copied over all my custom scripts, documents, cron.x, systemd/sysyem-sleep, etc. After two days of LIBC headaches and `apt-get` not working I just bit the bullet and got it done. Even though I had daily backups I think I only needed to restore one file.

Comment: I found another thread, problem similar to ours. Did you try this https://superuser.com/questions/1094401/any-way-to-solve-version-glibc-2-17-not-found ?